# how to minimal WAN data transfer delay time?

Tags: c++

i have some idea about file remote location.Can i split a file in to chunks and use thread control split and  socket to implement split data and send meanwhile ?
Besides, local can prefetch remote chunk and read it by two thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one source of data and one sink I would assume that chunking won't help. 
The IP-stack itself uses this method, so as long as you can provide data fast enough to the TCP stack (write buffer) and are fast enough reading the data from the buffer (read buffer) I think that is as fast as it gets...